# KeyError at /webhook/ 'HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'

Tags: django, stripe-payments

Following is my code for webhook with a Django application

```
@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
    webhook_secret = STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
    payload = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    signature = request.META["HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE"]
    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload=payload, sig_header=signature, secret=webhook_secret)
        data = event['data']
    except Exception as e:
        return e
    event_type = event['type']
    data_object = data['object']

    if event_type == 'invoice.paid':
        webhook_object = data["object"]
        stripe_customer_id = webhook_object["customer"]
        stripe_sub = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(webhook_object["subscription"])
        stripe_price_id = stripe_sub["plan"]["id"]
        current_period_end = stripe_sub["current_period_end"]
        current_period_end = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(current_period_end, tz=None)

        pricing = Pricing.objects.get(stripe_price_id=stripe_price_id)
        user = User.objects.get(stripe_customer_id=stripe_customer_id)
        subscription = Subscription.objects.get(user=user)
        subscription.status = stripe_sub["status"]
        subscription.stripe_subscription_id = webhook_object["subscription"]
        subscription.pricing = pricing
        subscription.current_period_end = current_period_end
        subscription.save()


    if event_type == 'customer.subscription.deleted':
        webhook_object = data["object"]
        stripe_customer_id = webhook_object["customer"]
        stripe_sub = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(webhook_object["id"])
        user = User.objects.get(stripe_customer_id=stripe_customer_id)
        subscription = Subscription.objects.get(user=user)
        subscription.status = stripe_sub["status"]
        subscription.save()

    return HttpResponse()
```

and the url is

```
path('webhook/', webhook, name='webhook')
```

if I check the path https://example.com/webhook/, I am getting the error

```
Exception Type: KeyError at /webhook/
Exception Value: 'HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'
```

and in strpe account I am getting 500 error

Comment: The KeyError indicates that `HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE` doesn't exist in the request headers - which is quite expected if you visit that URL manually.

Comment: Thank you, now need to sort out why I am getting 500 error in stripe webhook event

Answer (score 0):

It takes the POST request, whenever you hit the URL then it will show you this error because of the GET request.

run these commands:

```
$ stripe login 
$ stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/webhook
```

you can follow this said by [stripe](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/webhooks/create?endpoint_location=local) itself.